# How to generate statistics using list item fields (preferrably within SharePoint)?

Tags: list, custom-list, statistics

In dealing with large lists, it would be helpful to be able to generate some kind of statistical report using a given column/columns. For example ideally we would like to able to find the % of items that are incomplete (using a column entitled 'completion' whose allowed inputs are 'incomplete' and 'complete) within the list and also for an individual. Can this be done and if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Just a quick thanks for the response; it would have been perfect if my own skill in coding weren't so lacking but in the meantime)

I chanced across this webpart http://www.amrein.com/apps/page.asp?Q=5749 which provides a simple and free out of box solution to making graphs from list data.

Answer (score -1):

You can create an dashboard using xslt to display the required calcuations.

Refer links provided here :

http://paylord.wordpress.com/2012/05/05/xslt-dashboard/

http://www.myfatblog.co.uk/index.php/2009/10/creating-a-sales-dashboard-using-the-dataviewwebpart-xsl/

http://books.google.co.in/books?id=fBPvwkVCUQEC&pg=PT286&lpg=PT286&dq=xslt+dashboard+%2B+sharepoint+2010&source=bl&ots=WGaThJW0qD&sig=dZauP6eU8cU8X-pAYQyOTdWZJbo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=tbvnUZ6MGYeGrQfmuoCoBw&ved=0CE0Q6AEwBw

http://padavis.wordpress.com/2008/10/07/creating-a-dashboard-bar-chart-in-sharepoint-from-a-data-view/

Answer (score -1):

Refer links provided here :

http://paylord.wordpress.com/2012/05/05/xslt-dashboard/

http://www.myfatblog.co.uk/index.php/2009/10/creating-a-sales-dashboard-using-the-dataviewwebpart-xsl/

http://books.google.co.in/books?id=fBPvwkVCUQEC&pg=PT286&lpg=PT286&dq=xslt+dashboard+%2B+sharepoint+2010&source=bl&ots=WGaThJW0qD&sig=dZauP6eU8cU8X-pAYQyOTdWZJbo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=tbvnUZ6MGYeGrQfmuoCoBw&ved=0CE0Q6AEwBw

http://padavis.wordpress.com/2008/10/07/creating-a-dashboard-bar-chart-in-sharepoint-from-a-data-view/

Comment: Same goes here, do not add multiple answers, edit the first one.

Comment: Thank you, I don't suppose you know whether the same xslt codes for modifying the Data View Web Part will work for SharePoint2010?

Comment: yes, it will work

Comment: I tried making a bar chart in SPD 2010 and although it does seem to change the layout of the data and it does indeed make bars, the bars are unfilled and blank. Any ideas? (I'm afraid I'm a complete noob at XSL,) I'm sorry for pestering you.